# Unable to get milliseconds from GetSystemTime()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1, platform-builder

I am trying to print out seconds and milliseconds resolution timing and i am using `GetSystemTime()`.

This is my code:

```
GetSystemTime(&datetime);
RETAILMSG(1,(_T("Time After Data Sent to USB: %d:%d\r\n"), datetime.wSecond, datetime.wMilliseconds));
```

I print to the platform builder debug output using `RETAILMSG()`, but i am only able to print up to seconds resolution, so i will see something like **48:0** where the milliseconds is blank.

I am not sure why this is happening as i receive no complaints. I figure it has something to do with the implementation of `RETAILMSG()`.

Is there a fix for this or a substitute that i can use to achieve milliseconds resolution?

Thanks,

**EDIT: I am developing in Windows Embedded Compact 7**

Comment: Seems odd that it would be blank and not zero. Suggests a problem with the printf-like function you're using rather than the milliseconds field as such.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I typo'd. It is actually zero. I fixed it in my post.

Comment: Does std::chrono::high_resolution_clock do any better on WEC7?

Comment: You can use [`CUsAccurateTime::GetTime`](http://alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Common/alax.info/roatlcom.h?rev=482#L3478) to get 64-bit integer compatible with `FILETIME` (you can convert it to `SYSTEMTIME` using standard API). The class combines live clock time alignment with `QueryPerformanceCounter` accuracy for intervals, and gets high accuracy estimations. You can find similar implementations on StackOverflow as well. This is similar to [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API introduced with Win 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under windows, the clock resolution [is around 15ms](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx).

If you need millisecond resolution, there is a high performance clock that enables you to measure timebelow 10µs range (see [here: *Acquiring high-resolution time stamps*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on msdn).

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you provided does not show that QPC is supported in Windows Embedded Compact 7, so i do not think i have that api available. I edited my post to specify the platform.

Comment: I don't know the Embedded Compact environment, but this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488415%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx) suggest that `QueryPerformanceCounter` should be available.  (P.S: It might interest you also:  The first link in the answer shows a microsoft document explaining that in embedded environments, a system clock below 15 ms would significantly impact energy consumption)

Comment: Ah, the second link was very helpful. I will try this out and see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> the milliseconds is blank.
>
> I am not sure why this is happening

The [Embedded Compact documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Ee488017.aspx) for `GetSystemTime()` states the following warning about that issue:

> Millisecond granularity may not be supported by a hardware platform. The caller of this function should not rely on more than second granularity.